# Core Data / Cocoa : @distinctUnionOfObjects not returning a usable NSArray*

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an application that uses Core Data that has a relationship that I would like to group by. I have NSManagedObject classes that were generated by my .xcdatamodel file, and everything seems to be working OK for the most part.

Given a parent / child relationship, I would like to do the following:

A parent has a collection of children. The children have a property, groupByProperty, that I would like to group on.

The following code:

```
NSSet *allChildren = parent.children;
NSArray *groups = [allChildren valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.groupByProperty"];
Child *child = [groups objectAtIndex:x]; //x is the row that I would like to retrieve
```

produces an NSInvalidArgumentException when trying to set the child pointer.

However, when I do this:

```
NSSet *allChildren = parent.children;
NSArray *groups = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[allChildren valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.groupByProperty"]];
Child *child = [groups objectAtIndex:x]; //x is the row that I would like to retrieve
```

everything works fine.

Can anyone explain this behavior? I'm going nuts trying to figure out how this works.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide...

Chris

Comment: The code you're showing is no different, except that you leak the array you allocked in the second example (since you don't send it a release message, at least that we can see). Please edit your question to include the complete exception message as printed to the Debugger Console.

Comment: This is the error. It seems as though the object returned from valueForKeyPath: is not actually an NSArray. It's odd though, because initWithArray: requires an NSArray* passed to it... it's very weird!

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFSet objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a3ff60'

Comment: Also, Peter, I am releasing groups further down in the code. I just made this snippet for simplicity to show what was causing the crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I got my information from this Apple document: [Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html), where it states "***The @distinctUnionOfObjects operator returns an array containing the distinct objects returned by sending valueForKeyPath: to each item in the receiver, passing the key path to the right of the array operator."*** I assumed that the returned object is an NSArray, because it says "Array", when it should probably say "Array or Set". I changed the returned Object to an NSSet, and then used [[groups allObjects] objectAtIndex:x] to get my object out of there.

It now looks like this:

```
NSSet *allChildren = parent.children;
NSSet *groups = [allChildren valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.groupByProperty"];
Child *child = [[groups allObjects] objectAtIndex:x]; //x is the row that I would like to retrieve
```

Thanks for your help, I guess I just needed to look at the exception a little bit more carefully, the key here being "-[**NSCFSet** objectAtIndex:....."

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot until 2 days after post. I will then for sure!

Answer (score 3):

You should do the following:

```
NSArray *groups = [parent valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.children.groupByProperty"];
Child *child = [groups objectAtIndex:x];
```